# Measure on compact

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am tryying to solve exercise:
Let $K \subset R$ is compact with no isolated point.

Find Borel nonatomic measure $\xi$ on $R$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(\xi)=K$

Thank's on all help.

Comment: First construct a homeomorphic copy of Cantor $C$ set inside $K$. Now note that you can define a measure on $C$ by lifting the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$ to the $C$ via the function $f:[0, 1] \to C$ defined by $f(x) = \sum_n 2a_n/3$ where $0.a_1a_2a_3 \dots$ is the binary expansion of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

My original hint was a little off. Here's a (hopefully) better one.

First, assume that all connected components of $K$ are singletons; in this case, you can show that $K$ is homeomorphic to $2^{\bf N}$, which holds a measure with full support.

For arbitrary $K$, the connected components are (closed) intervals and singletons. It's easy to find a measure supported by the intervals. What is left when you take them away?

Comment: is left only set of measure zero, I think. I can find measure on some closed interval(because it has a countable(dense)basis)...Am I right??...But how many intervals there is in K??Countable infinte?? Please, try explaine to me. Thank's a lot on your answer and your help.

Comment: @user207950: what is left has Lebesgue measure zero true, but you want it to be in support. The point is, if you remove the closed intervals, take the closure of what's left, this will be a totally disconnected compact set without isolated points, so you can take the measure constructed according to the second paragraph (and add it to Lebesgue measure restricted to the original set).